# Running a shell script: permission denied

Tags: shell, permissions

I have just started my first python project. When it comes to running the shell script, the following error appears. What can be the cause of that problem? Maybe it is easy to solve. Thanks for your help, I am glad to provide more specific information as you need.

Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97zVU.png)

Comment: Please replace the image with formatted code/text. See [help] and especially [mre].

Comment: searching anywhere on the internet for "linux permissions denied" should have found you many explanations and solutions. The purpose of S.O. is that you search for an answer, and only if you can't find a solution do you submit a question. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `chmod +x <name of script>`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your script is not executable. To see if it is, do ls -l in directory and look for a -x on the beginning of your script name. To make it executable do chmod +x scriptName